# How to draw a line parallel to y = x line using matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I was wondering how to draw two lines above and below the y=x line at distance sigma = 1?

## MWE

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 8,8
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 16})

plt.style.use('ggplot')
%matplotlib inline

x = np.arange(11)
y = x
plt.plot(x,y)
```

## Output

[image]

## Question

Are there any numpy/scipy function to draw lines above and below y=x line at given distance.
I am aware of axhline and axvline but I am not sure how to draw parallel to y=x line.
Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this to plot parallel line above and below.

```py
y1 = x + 1
y2 = x - 1
plt.plot(y1,x)
plt.plot(y2,x)
plt.show()
```

In order to get the exact distance you must then calculate the offset needed. And instead of `1` use that offset.

**EDIT** 
as @Julien correctly pointed out. use offset `c = d/sqrt(2)`.

```
c = d/sqrt(2) # d = required distance
y1 = x + c
y2 = x - c
```

Comment: this will not produce a distance of 1 but 1/sqrt(2).

Comment: You need to calculate the y-intercept of the line.  Draw the two lines on graph paper, draw the right triangle including one line, the y-axis, and the line segment perpendicular to both lines.  Solve the triangle; this is junior-high algebra, and can be found in many places.

Comment: The offset depends on the slope of the original line and the distance you want.  For your given case, pick a variable point on the y-axis, `(0, a)`.  Draw a perpendicular segment to the red line.  You want the length of this segment to be 1.  You have the angles of the triangle (determined by the slope of the red line) and that `1` side; solve the triangle.  `a` is the needed offset.